# How to find number user login into the server on a specific date in linux (/var/log/secure) file

Tags: linux, redhat, centos8

How to find the number of users login into the server on a specific date in Linux (/var/log/secure) file?

Comment: might be more suitable for superuser.com rather than SO. You might want to add ```redhat``` or ```centos``` tag since that file seems only to exist in RHEL based distro.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following GNU awk solution:

```
awk -v dat="Feb 24" '$0 ~ dat && /Accepted password for/ { usr=gensub("(^.*)(Accepted password for[[:space:]])([^ ]+)(.*$)","\\3",$0);map[usr]=""} END { for (i in map) { cnt++ } print cnt}' /var/log/secure
```

Explanation:

```
awk -v dat="Feb 24"                                                              # Pass the date to awk as a variable - dat
'$0 ~ dat && /Accepted password for/ {                                           # Process the line when it contains the passed date and has "Accepted password for"
                                        usr=gensub("(^.*)(Accepted password for[[:space:]])([^ ]+)(.*$)","\\3",$0);                                              # Use awk's gensub function to extract the user from the line
                                        map[usr]=""                              # Create an array map with the usr as the index
                                     }
                                 END { 
                                        for (i in map) { 
                                           cnt++                                 # Count the number of users in the map array
                                        } 
                                        print cnt                                # Print the cnt
                                      }' /var/log/secure
```

Comment: Does  this solution, help?

Comment: Great. If it helps, please take the time to up vote and select the solution as an answer.